# disable IIS Express?

Tags: iis

Just migrated to VS2012 and having this issue. I need to develop against real IIS server (to be able to debug web services when they called from network devices)

Having issues with "IIS Express started on same port", etc. But there seems to be no IIS Manager for Express? How do I control and configure it?

I'd rather fall back to real IIS

Comment: Well, years later Jexus Manager for IIS Express comes, https://jexus.codeplex.com/releases/view/138373

Answer (score 3):

1. Register asp.net

   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
2. `Open Project-> Right Click Select Properties-> Select Web Tab-> Select Use Local IIS Web Server & uncheck the Use IIS Express checkbok -> Specify Project Url`

[image]

Comment: IIS won't start on port 80 because IIS Express already there. I solved it already, uninstalled IIS Express completely

Comment: @katit, could you elaborate on how exactly you uninstall express? I'm interested in doing it too.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall IIS Express via Windows 10

Go to Settings -> Apps and features -> Select IIS Express -> Uninstall

Note: IIS Express is packaged with Visual Studio installation (if you have selected to develop ASP.NET Web applications). I DO NOT KNOW if uninstalling IIS Express will have undesirable repercussions in your VS IDE.

I would just follow the instructions above rather than completely uninstalling IIS Express.

Cheers!

Comment: VS IDE - it fails